# Отличие в скорости вычисления тригонометрических функций в Java и C#

Tags: java, c#

Изучаю Java и заинтересовался работой метода `sin` (`cos`). Заметил, что скорость получения синуса на j меняется в зависимости от аргумента функции. Если угол меньше 0.785... рад, то вычисляет быстро, а если больше - соответственно, медленно.

Сравнил с C#, получилось примерно наоборот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Проверял в миллисекундах за 10 млн вычислений синуса.
Почему результаты таковы?

---

Вот результат для косинуса/синуса java от 0 до 4*pi:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {        
    long a;
    for (double x = 0; x < 4 * Math.PI; x = x + 0.05) {
        a = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
            //Math.cos(x);
            Math.sin(x);
        }
        System.out.printf("%.6f, %d \n", x, (System.currentTimeMillis() - a));
    }
}
```

---

Вот результат для косинуса/синуса C# от 0 до 4*pi:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        for (double x = 0; x < 4 * Math.PI; x = x + 0.05) {
            Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
            sw.Start();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
                Math.Cos(x);
                // Math.Sin(x);
            }
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine(x +" - " +(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds).ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы используете разные способы измерить время, на мой взгляд причина вполне может быть в этом. С какой точностью работает в `java` метод `currentTimeMillis`? Попробуйте ещё на порядок увеличить количество вычислений. Будет сохраняться такая картина?

Comment: sin и cos в некотром смысле противоположны, поэтому в C# может вполне вычисляться cos, а java -- sin

Comment: Прогоните и косинус таким же тестом, интересно в свете ответа @Barmaley.

Comment: Проверил у себя в C# .Net Framework v4.0.30319, наблюдаю картину аналогичную Java - возрастающий участок. На косинусе ровно противоположные показатели - убывающий участок.

Comment: @Monk точность времени по-умолчанию в одну млсек. Да, сохраняется картна.

Comment: @Eugene Krivenja, простая замена Math.sin на cos ничего не изменяет в результатах на j. Такие же значения времени при исходных углах.

Comment: @Alex Krass .Net v4.0.30319

Comment: Никогда не понимал смысл вот этих вот подсчетов. Зачем они?

Comment: @Flippy я думаю, что все эти подсчёты разные. На этапе проектирования приложения иногда возникает задача выбрать язык. Ведь может оказаться полезным? Некоторые любят разгадывать загадки.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

По C# не скажу точно, но по Java — всё выглядит так:

1. Синус вычисляется через Сишную библиотеку FDLIB. Исходники [здесь](http://www.netlib.org/fdlibm/k_sin.c).
2. Для аппроксимации синуса используется полином 13-й степени (что-то типа Чебышева).
3. При этом для величин аргумента менее `PI/4=0.785` вычисляется истинный синус.
4. Если аргумент больше `PI/4` вычисляется уже через косинус, который аппроксимируется уже полиномом 14-й степени, оттуда и происходит скачок на графике.

Скорее всего, с C# история аналогичная, только используется другая библиотека.

Comment: Спасибо. Пока что не совсем понятно, потому что с косинусом на j идентичная синусу картина. А должен быть отличающийся график, если я правильно понял.

Comment: Вот результат от 0 до 4*pi на j для sin и cos.
 https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/xvJPIa09lcbgXafyznDZr5755VqLttKLxpYjp0toH3aIZJCJLqTq2pn010ze4ebvMAcYIW0qYR2FQXw=w1920-h949-rw

Comment: Вот C# от 0 до 4*pi: 
https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/e7Gonzn1mbANt2g6Mx15bg0Zm6mn3L28bT-PBo_zR5CP6rTnF4qKZ7oisIH_JUmRoPYZ__f980kFB1E=w1920-h949-rw

Comment: Честно, слабо разбираюсь в С\С++, но возможно это [исходник math](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/72c57d9d9fd2d4cd8c96f124d132d316c8ef6013/src/pal/src/cruntime/math.cpp) для дотнета(core).